# How to crawl images in Nutch 2.3 as HBase as backend?

Tags: nutch

I want to crawl images from certain sites. So far I tried modifiying
regex-urlfilter.txt.

I changed:

```
 -\.(gif|GIF|jpg|JPG|png|PNG|ico|ICO|css|CSS|sit|SIT|eps|EPS|wmf|WMF|zip|ZIP|ppt|PP
 T|mpg|MPG|xls|XLS|gz|GZ|rpm|RPM|tgz|TGZ|mov|MOV|exe|EXE|jpeg|JPEG|bmp|BMP|js|JS)$
```

To:

```
-\.(css|CSS|sit|SIT|eps|EPS|wmf|WMF|zip|ZIP|ppt|PPT|mpg|MPG|xls|XLS|gz|GZ|rpm|RPM|t
gz|TGZ|mov|MOV|exe|EXE|js|JS)$
```

But it didn't work. I am surprised that I didn't find any documentation regarding ***crawling images using Nutch 2.3***. Referal to any existing documentation would really be a great help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to fetch and store images using Nutch you have to follow these steps:

1- Adding regular expression to not filter image formats, such as jpg, jpeg, tif, gif, png and etc... (which you already did)

2- Implementing a parse plugin for parsing images. For more information about Nutch extension points and writing required plugin follow these links:

http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/AboutPlugins

http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/WritingPluginExample

3- Tell Nutch about the implemented plugin and using that for image file formats:

For this purpose you have to follow two different steps, first, modify conf/parse-plugins.xml and map your implemented plugin to image file formats:

```
<mimeType name="image/jpeg">
        <plugin id="parse-image" />
</mimeType>
<mimeType name="image/gif">
        <plugin id="parse-image" />
</mimeType>
<mimeType name="image/png">
        <plugin id="parse-image" />
</mimeType>
```

second, add the implemented plugin to `nutch-site.xml` to be run at Nutch runtime. You have to add the implemented plugin to `<plugin.includes>` property.

Comment: Thanks Ali. That mean I will have to write my own plugin. Actually I was searching for existing ones.

Comment: Good explanation. @Ali n, Computergodzilla, Can you please provide a standard ImageParser if any?